# Стоит ли боятся DownCast'а(конкретизация типа)?

Tags: c#, .net

Допустим, есть 3 интерфейса:

1. Список свойств
2. Список методов
3. Наследуется от 2-ух интерфейсов

Какой-то класс хранит в себе экземпляр 3-го интерфейса.

И я хочу, что бы в классе было свойство, которое возвращает 3-ий интерфейс, но пониженный до 1-го.

Собственно вопрос:

А я должен боятся того, что кто-то за пределами моего класса выполнит повышающее преобразование и получат интерфейс под номером 3 и получат доступ к методам, которые могут поломать все?

Если порассуждать, то даже если я спрячу данные в отдельный класс и буду возвращать его, то в теории, если юзер захочет, то он может хакнуть все через рефлексию- это конечно будет чуть труднее, но реализуемо.

Comment: Это вам решать - бояться чего то или нет. Если вы пишете библиотеку, то наверное надо этот как то учитывать. Если вы пишете свой проект, то, кмк, можно не заморачиваться.

Comment: @tym32167 да я думаю, как наиболее правильно. Просто, не хочу наружу методы интерфейса передавать и хочу только данные. Собственно, или мне положиться на даункаст или возвращать отдельный тип только с этими полями.

Comment: правильно возвращать только то, что требуется клиенту, но это не абсолютное правило, скорее, рекомендация.

Comment: @tym32167 ну даункастом я этого могу добиться, но тогда я должен наедятся на честность пользователя. Однако, в теории, если конечный пользователь захочет "хакнуть" класс, то он может это сделать рефлексией.

Comment: Вообще, сейчас у меня все в 1 интерфейсе- и методы и свойства. Однако подумав, я предположил, что проблему можно решить разбиением на 3 интерфейса.

Comment: Сделать upcast это секундное дело, какой нибудь джуниор, который любит костыли, когда увидит ваш тип в дебаге, скорее всего этот upcast и сделает по глупости. А вот рефоексия - это уже конкретные намерения, если клиент завязался на рефлексии, то он сам себе злобный буратино и он сам уже отвечает за то. что творит.

Comment: @tym32167 upcast к internal-типу не сделать. `@iluxa1810 у вас интерфейс 3 интернальный?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Нет.

Comment: @АндрейNOP а смысл в internal интерфейсе?

Comment: @tym32167 ну... костыли будут на совести того, кто сделал апкаст. Я же спрашиваю больше по тому: Стоит ли оберегать конечного пользователя от выстрела себе в ногу или правильный пользователь не должен захотеть делать апкасты, если я возвращаю пониженный тип?

Comment: Одной из причин введения ReadOnly-коллекций (IReadOnly-интерфейсов) было как раз то, что их нельзя скастить. То есть полностью устранили такую проблему. Значит, опасались именно таких действий. А вот для объектов такого простого способа нет.

Comment: Кажется я попутал термины UpCast и DownCast. UpCast ведь приведение к более абстрактному, а DownCast к более конкретному? Я имел ввиду конкретизация типа

Comment: Если вы пишете библиотеку, то вы её пишете для конечного юзера, то есть легкость работы с вашей библиотекой будет определяющим фактором и, соответсвено, конечному юзеру должно быть максимально комфортно работать с такой библиотекой.

Comment: `Я имел ввиду конкретизация типа` я так и понял ваш вопрос )

Comment: я бы просто нафигарил 3 декоратора, один для каждого интерфейса, и все дела.

Comment: @tym32167 приведите пример.

Answer (score 5):

Допустим, есть 3 интерфейса

```
public interface IInterface1
{
    void Method1();
}

public interface IInterface2
{
    void Method2();
}

public interface IInterface3
{
    void Method3();
}
```

и общий интерфейс

```
public  interface IInterfaceComon : IInterface1, IInterface2, IInterface3 {}
```

Класс, что всё реализует

```
private class MyClass : IInterfaceComon
{
    public void Method1(){}
    public void Method2(){}
    public void Method3(){}
}
```

Декораторы

```
private class Decor1 : IInterface1
{
    private IInterface1 _inner; 
    public Decor1(IInterface1 inner)=>_inner = inner;
    public void Method1()=> _inner.Method1();           
}

private class Decor2 : IInterface2
{
    private IInterface2 _inner;
    public Decor2(IInterface2 inner) => _inner = inner;
    public void Method2() => _inner.Method2();
}

private class Decor3 : IInterface3
{
    private IInterface3 _inner;
    public Decor3(IInterface3 inner) => _inner = inner;
    public void Method3() => _inner.Method3();
}
```

Логика

```
public class MyLogic
{
    public IInterface1 GetInterfce1(){
        return new Decor1(new MyClass());
    }

    public IInterface2 GetInterfce2()
    {
        return new Decor2(new MyClass());
    }

    public IInterface3 GetInterfce3()
    {
        return new Decor3(new MyClass());
    }
}
```

Вот и всё, никакие касты не помогут, но если клиент заморочился рефлексией - то он сам себе создает проблемы.

Сами декораторы будут меняться с такой же частотой, как и интерфейсы, то есть максимально редко. Один раз написал и забыл.

Отмечу, что это просто защита от дурака, её писать не обязательно, но если вы ожидаете много пытливых клиентов, то желательно. В идеальном мире клиенты не должны кастить ничего из ваших классов, так как в таком случае они не следуют контракту вашего класса, а делают какие то предположения о вашем классе.